# What's another name for the non-negative quadrant, or any non-negative orthant?

Tags: geometry

Is there another canonical name for the non-negative quadrant, or for the generic non-negative orthant?

Comment: Thos are usually referred to as the *1st* quadrant / octant etc.

Comment: Yes, but is there a single more expressive word for it?

Comment: "Non-negative orthant" sounds perfectly clear to me; even if it's not a standard term, I understand what it means.

Comment: I believe "primary orthant" and "principal orthant" have been used.

Comment: Thanks, "principal orthant" is a nice alternative.

Comment: In some contexts "nonnegative cone" might be a clear enough reference to this subset.

Comment: Would that not be "positive semidefinite cone"?

Comment: Works for me, or even closed positive cone.